# how to draw transparent polygon in openGL

Tags: opengl

I need your help. I know there is alpha in openGL, and it's help me to draw polygon on transparent mode, but I do not know how to do that, what should enable to allow opengGL to draw that polygon.

and thanks for any help.

Comment: You should click the Tick to accept matias.valdenegro's answer :)

Answer (score 19):

It's simple:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Enable blending.
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //Set blending function.
```

That's the basic, that blending function is the basic and should be fine for you, but there are others.

Then, you need to be sure that your window/framebuffer contains an alpha channel, and that the polygons you draw also contain alpha information.

Answer (score 8):

It is exactly as Matias says, but you should also remember that to get the "transparency" work as it is supposed, all the non-transparent primitives in the scene must be drawn first, and the transparent ones must be drawn in the correct order, from the back of Z-buffer towards the front.

The reason for this is that OpenGL doesn't really support transparency, it emulates it through alpha-blending, and so if a new object is drawn behind a "transparent" primitive after it has already been rendered, the new object will not be visible through it.